# Assertions on arguments of called methods using Mockito but without ArgumentCaptor

Tags: java, testing, mockito

When *verifying* multiple different calls to a method of a mock, it is possible to call `verify()` twice for each invocation.

This will work when not using matchers:

```java
    @Test
    @DisplayName("verify two different calls")
    void verifyTwoDifferentCalls() {
        someMock.someMethod(1, "any string");
        someMock.someMethod(2, "any string");

        verify(someMock).someMethod(1, "any string");
        verify(someMock).someMethod(2, "any string");
    }
```

This will also work when using simple matchers:

```java
    @Test
    @DisplayName("verify two different calls with eq()")
    void verifyTwoDifferentCallsWithEq() {
        someMock.someMethod(1, "any string");
        someMock.someMethod(2, "any string");

        verify(someMock).someMethod(eq(1), anyString());
        verify(someMock).someMethod(eq(2), anyString());
    }
```

However, it does not work when using `assertArg()`:

```java
    @Test
    @DisplayName("verify two different calls with asserArg()")
    void verifyTwoDifferentCallsWithAsserArg() {
        someMock.someMethod(1, "any string");
        someMock.someMethod(2, "any string");

        verify(someMock).someMethod(
            assertArg(someInt -> assertThat(someInt).isEqualTo(1)),
            anyString()
        );
        verify(someMock).someMethod(
            assertArg(someInt -> assertThat(someInt).isEqualTo(2)),
            anyString()
        );
    }
```

The reason behind this is probably the inner assertion failing on at least one of the calls.
[image]

So far, the only way I know how to test something like this is to use `ArgumentCaptor`s:

```java
    @Test
    @DisplayName("verify two different calls with ArgumentCaptor")
    void verifyTwoDifferentCallsWithArgumentCaptor() {
        someMock.someMethod(1, "any string");
        someMock.someMethod(2, "any string");

        final ArgumentCaptor<Integer> someIntCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Integer.class);

        verify(someMock, times(2)).someMethod(someIntCaptor.capture(), anyString());

        assertThat(someIntCaptor.getAllValues()).containsExactly(1, 2);
    }
```

Now, my question: Is there any way to do this without using an `ArgumentCaptor`?

Comment: Indeed, assertArg does not play well with multiple verifications of the same method - the assertion error is immediately propagated. Does a custom matcher / argThat fulfill your needs? If not, please explain why, ideally with a code example

Comment: That would definitely be an option, but I was hoping that Mockito could already do that. I will try and come up with something.